# After stopping Yami in her Darkness Mode, how long did it take for Lala to recover her teenager body?

Tags: to-love-ru

In the finale of To Love-Ru Darkness, Lala spends all her energy on her tail beam, to stop Darkness's energy blade from slicing the town (and probably the planet).

As a side-effect of such energy spending, she reverts to a preteen ぺたんこ body. It causes Yami to give her lots and lots of [milk bottles](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BreastExpansion).

How long does it take for her body to recover? (you can answer in how many chapters (since time is not closely kept in the story) or episodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 22 manga chapters, anime unknown

In the manga, Lala uses her tail beam and becomes a child in Chapter 44, "Power and Power ~Protector and Protected~".

It was actually pretty hard to track down when she gets her sexy adult body back, because her child body bears an incredible likeness to Momo, Nana, and Yami in certain scenes, especially when they're naked, which they frequently are, because it's To-Love-Ru. This made it necessary to read a lot of the context, which slowed down a casual scan. But Lala's growth back to her usual body is the main plot of Chapter 66, "Delight ~Growth of Body and Heart~". So it takes 22 chapters.

There's no clear sense of how much time passes in-universe between these two chapters, but once Lala starts growing, it takes her about a day to grow back to her original body, as stated by Peke at the beginning of Chapter 66.

I haven't watched the anime of *Darkness*, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_To_Love-Ru_episodes#To_Love-Ru_Darkness_2nd_.282016_OVA_series.29), Lala is still in her child form as of the third episode of the most recent series, the 2016 OVA *To Love-Ru Darkness 2nd*, so it's unclear when the anime will have her regain her adult body.

Comment: She is a child still in the 3rd OVA (the one with the shrinking of  Haruna + Rito and the subsequent fail-train wreck) that is the last anime released at the time off this posting I think so.